# Maven - Exclude class files from war

Tags: maven-2, war

I have :

```
src/main/java/com.tuto
```

- `Class1.java`
- `Class2.java`
- `Class3.java`

My pom is packaging a war.
So in my war, in `WEB-INF/classes/com/tuto` I found the 3 classes.

Now I want to exclude Class2.java

I tried

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                 <exclude>**/Class2.class</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But it's not working.

How can I do ?

---

Ok, so like Aaron tell me, this is working :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>**/Class2.class</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But ...

Let's take the problem by the other side : I want to exclude all except Class1 and Class3

So I tried

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingIncludes>**/Class1.class,**/Class3.class</packagingIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and this time it's not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As the documentation says](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html), you should use the `packagingExcludes` element instead.

Note that `packagingExcludes` doesn't use nested elements. Instead, the content is a "comma-separated list of Ant file set patterns".

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html), excludes will take higher priority over includes. In your case, use packagingExcludes for excluding class2 explicitly.

```
<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/com/tuto/Class2.class</packagingExcludes>
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete plugin xml should be like the following

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${build.output.directory}</outputDirectory>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/ItemConsumer.class</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

add plugin to pom.xml - 100% working properly.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--package path you want to delete-->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/lk/**</packagingExcludes>

                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!--project build path-->
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/target/classes/</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes><include>**/*.class</include></includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```